# What Javascript libraries are available to import wallets with mnemonic keys, other than by beacon?

Tags: wallets, beacon, conseiljs, programming

I want my dApp to have an in-app wallet which, once imported, will allow full control of it.
I need this to automate transactions, that will be sent without the presence of the owner.
I have already done this in the past, using my own library (TezosJ_plainJava). However, I need a Javascript solution, as the idea is to run the code on the user browser and without APIs or back-end servers.

As far as I know, the only library that still allows this kind of thing is ConseilJS. I would like to know if there is any alternative.

Comment: Whats the name of function that can do this in ConseilJS. Or can you point me to the documentation on ConseilJS to that point where its described? At the moment I do not know about any alternative library but what comes to my mind is to create a feature request on Taquito so Taquito adds that?

Comment: Never mind. I've just been informed that Taquito does what I need with the "In Memory Signer" option. Anyways, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I've been told that I can indeed use Taquito's "In memory signer" to do what I want (import a wallet without beacon).